# How to cover/improvise percentage in SONAR CUBE Report by REST Assured Test Cases?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, rest-assured

How to cover SONAR CUBE Report for  REST Assured Test Cases? 
Is there any possible way to improve code coverage in SONAR Using REST Assured Test Cases.

Since I am using some api's & microservices I used REST assured test case.
But it is not covering in SONAR CUBE.

*(Note: I have already used JACOCO plugin Report coverage ..It does not show the covering classes where i have used Rest Assured)*